# Bootstrap vertical align property not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

A very basic question from the documentation of Bootstrap. Everything seemed to have worked so far, except this **vertical alignment**. In the following images you can see [How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBZSl.png) and [How it appears in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBevS.png).

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col align-self-start">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col align-self-center">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col align-self-end">
          One of three columns
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

**Vertical center is relative to height.** In your example, all of the **sibling columns are the same height** so you're not going to see any variation in alignment.

Either the `.row` needs to have a defined height, *or* some content in the columns causes the row to have more height.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="height:180px">
        <div class="col align-self-start">
            One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col align-self-center">
            One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col align-self-end">
            One of three columns
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/aCGgDtzhdY

Comment: @user7759474 Did this work? please accept the answer so others know the question is solved

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using static heights or widths you can use a bootstrap predefined class **"vh-100" or "vw-100" which means "height: 100vh" or "width: 100vh"**.

viewport height and widths refers to the whole viewport and it's a relative measure across different devices and their sizes. 100vh it's also a percentage, so 100vh it's equal to 100%.

You can add just vh-100 to your tag classes or create a new class with some other properties to customize your component/tag.

```
.custom-size {
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: red;
 }


<div class="row custom-size">Something here</div> //custom class
<div class="row vh-100 bg-primary">Something here</div> // bootstrap predefined classes
```