# Bootstrap 4 - align-items-* class not working at all

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am currently building a website with Bootstrap 4 framework. I noticed that I can't align items properly.

Example:

[Bootstrap 4 official documentation row positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNaNF.jpg)

[My row positioning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vglT8.jpg)

Code according to the docs:

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In similar questions the advice was to put min-height property on the parent class , but that did not fixed my problem.

I know that probably, this is a dumb question , but I'm newbie in bootstrap.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: for bootstrap5 it works if `align-content-??`  replaced by `justify-content-end` , `-center` or   
 `-start`

Comment: @CodeToLife Thanks! Your comment is the only “answer” for *horizontal* centering. lol In my case, I needed to use `col d-flex justify-content-center` (where `col` can be any of the column variants such as `col-md-6` etc). Also, it's easy to mix this up with `align-items-center` which is similar. [Bootstrap Flex Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The parent of those div aka the `div.row` has no height, it's height is defined by it's content aka those divs you're trying to align vertically, therefore there's no space for those div to be aligned as they should be.

as you may have notice in that particularly example they have, you can see the pink background, that is the `div.row` and it have a min-height of 10rm.

**see picture below**

[image]

Basically you need a height for things to move in the vertical space.

**Simple example**

```css
.row {
  height: 5em;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

.container>.row>div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container>.row>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.container>.row>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-end">
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't you talking about vertical alignment here? I think OP was talking about horizontal alignment, which in my case it not working either.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 I'm pretty sure the op's question is about vertical alignment, However horizontal alignment isn't different at all, you'll need a width and the elements shouldn't occupy all the space.

Comment: @TheRealChx101 you can post a question or leave me a link to a snippet, I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: I make the same mistake. HAHA. Btw, ths a lot

Answer (score 1):

I've already [answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50657084/bootstrap-vertical-align-property-not-working/50657362#50657362).

**Vertical center is relative to height.** In your example, all of the sibling columns are the same height so you're not going to see any variation in alignment. 
Either the `.row` needs to have a defined height, *or* put some content in the columns that causes the row to have more height...

https://www.codeply.com/go/aCGgDtzhdY